# Improving appearance of vector tiles in Mapbox at various zoom levels

Tags: mapbox, vector-tiles, mbtiles, tippecanoe

I am wondering how I can better render large datasets in [Mapbox](https://www.mapbox.com/) for viewing purposes?

Currently I use an [`ogr2ogr`](https://gdal.org/programs/ogr2ogr.html) script to convert large [ESRI shapefiles](https://www.esri.com/library/whitepapers/pdfs/shapefile.pdf) to [MBTiles](https://docs.mapbox.com/help/glossary/mbtiles/).

```
ogr2ogr -f MBTILES -dsco MINZOOM=10 -dsco MAXZOOM=22 
C:\users\myself\path_to_output\target.mbtiles 
C:\users\myself\path_to_shp\source.shp
```

From this I then upload these MBtiles to Mapbox. However one issue I am noticing is the improperly rendered features at higher zoom levels.

This is an example of the Mapbox preview I upload the MBTile at zoom levels <16. This is an example of a shapefile that contains 200k point features within it. At zoom levels <16 there is a strange single point pattern than occurs rather than the more natural clustering that you see at the top.

[image: Zoomlv15]

However at zoom level 17, this is no longer an issue and is appears to be as normal.

[image: Zoomlv17]

Ideally there would be a way to display the datasets with a feature simplification at higher zoom levels that look more natural as opposed to the "dot grid" pattern in the first image.

One option I looked at was [tippecanoe](https://github.com/mapbox/tippecanoe) however is doesn't seem to be built natively for windows and the recommended install is via MacOS.

Would it be worth the hassle to install tippecanoe or is there an alternative available for Windows users for better rendering of large datasets in Mapbox for viewing?

Comment: tippecanoe also works on Linux, so you don't need a mac.

Comment: I actually have a Mac at home so I have decided to install tippecanoe on my home computer. It would be nice to be able to use it at the workplace but if it works out well then I might find a workaround for this problem or simply do this part at home. Thanks AndrewHarvey!